# AS3: How can I implement a perfect ROLL_OVER(or MOUSE_OVER) event listener on curved movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I've a problem with ROLL_OVER event listener. When I enter the empty area withing the movieclip with mouse cursor, ROLL_OVER event triggers. But I want that event trigger only when mouse cursor is on the colored area.

To Make it more clear: Think about " O " letter, when mouse cursor is between the empty area of O letter (inside of O) , event shouldn't trigger. It should trigger only when mouse curser is on the black area.

How can I implement this?

Thanks

-Ozan

PROBLEM IS SOLVED THANKS TO @Ethan Kennerly

I just want to add a few things to help people have problem same as me. In my situation I tried to make continents glow when my mouse is over them. I used the ROLL_OVER/MOUSE_OVER eventlistener to check if my mouse is over them or not. But with the data given by Ethan Kennerly I produced another way.
In Ethan Kennerly's solution, if your mouse enters the area of continent from a transparent area , it doesn't get blur effect because ROLL_OVER and MOUSE_OVER event listeners only trigger once per enters so I used MOUSE_MOVE event listener on each continent movieclips.
And for this statement:

```
if (isPixelTransparent(DisplayObject(event.currentTarget), new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)) {
    return;
}
```

add whatever is in the "ROLL_OUT or MOUSE_OUT" eventlistener function, add all of them inside this statement. But don't remove ROLL_OUT or MOUSE_OUT functions.

Comment: It's been a while since I had to do this. But, if I remember correctly, this is already how AS3 works. If your asset has a 'fill color' around the shape, then it won't work. But if you use a PNG with transparency or draw the shape in the Flash IDE, the space around it won't trigger the roll_over events.

Comment: MovieClips' already have only png format items inside.
There are 7 movieclips , each have different continents of world inside them. I've edited them in photoshop and imported into flash as png files, still doesn't work. :(

Comment: If you use vector content instead of PNGs that won't happen.

Comment: You know, you are right. When I import my PNG's, I often break them into a Vector after importing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the movie clip contains a shape that has transparent pixels.  Transparent pixels respond to mouse over and roll over.  If you could draw vector graphics that have no shapes with transparent pixels, the mouse would ignore the empty space in the movie clip's bounding box.

Yet it sounds like you need to use transparent pixels and you want the mouse to ignore them, so you could guard, like this:

```
private function onRollOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (isPixelTransparent(DisplayObject(event.currentTarget), new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)) {
        return;
    }
    // respond to roll over.
}
```

To detect transparency, Miguel Santirso rendered the pixels and translated the coordinate space here:  http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/97/check-if-a-pixel-is-transparent-in-a-displayobject  (Except line 38 looks on my computer like "rect" got rendered as "ct").  You could optimize that code by only drawing the pixel in question, instead of the whole image, and checking if that pixel value (getPixel32) is 0, instead of calling a hitTest.  I would optimize Miguel's code like this:

```
    public static function isPixelTransparent(objectOnStage:DisplayObject, globalPoint:Point):Boolean
    {
        var local:Point = objectOnStage.globalToLocal(globalPoint);
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.translate(-local.x, -local.y); 
        var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1, 1, true, 0x00000000);
        data.draw(object, matrix);
        return 0x00000000 == data.getPixel32(0, 0);
    }
```

By the way, if all your movie clips would have the same hit test shape, you could create a separate transparent shape that listens to the roll over.  I use a transparent shape to define a custom hit test shape that is a consistent and simple shape (like a circle) when the image is a more complicate shape (like an X or an O with nothing in the middle).  The custom hit test shape is a Sprite with a transparent shape.  The sprite listens to the roll over.  A separate mouse listener shape is also useful if your movie clip, on later frames, creates new shapes that alter the silhouette of the movie clip.

Comment: Although I don't know all the codes inside your solution(i'm weak on bitmap and matrix operations on as3), I understand what it does and it's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a nice, creative solution. I'd like to point out that this could be incredibly slow depending on device and how often it is used. Given how localized the data grab is, I don't think it will be, but the possibility exists that it could be run too often and on some devices (particularly Android and iOS), bitmap drawing and analyzing is actually very slow.

Comment: @JoshJanusch You're right.  If performance drops: a few optimizations come to mind.  Such as: Do not construct the instances locally (Point, Matrix, BitmapData); recycle the temporary instance.  Lower the resolution and cache.  Round to nearest 4x4 pixels, instead of every 1x1 pixel.  Memoize or precompute the result.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be using the Interactive PNG class by Moses.

http://blog.mosessupposes.com/?p=40

> Normally the clear areas of a PNG are treated as solid, which can be especially frustrating when dealing with a lot of images that overlap each other because they tend to block mouse interactions on the clips below them.
>
> This utility fixes that so that mouse events don't occur until you
>   bump against a solid pixel, or a pixel of any transparency value
>   besides totally clear. InteractivePNG lets you set an alphaTolerance
>   level to determine what transparency level will register as a hit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I found it a little complicated.

Comment: The problem with the accepted answer is that you will need to calculate the pixel's alpha on every click. Depending on the project and the platform that could lead to serious performance problems.

Using the Moses solution you only calculate the transparent pixels once.

Basically you use his class like a regular `MovieClip` and call `drawBitmapHitArea` when you want the hit are to be calculated. It's really easy to use...

Comment: Okay than I will study Moses solution when I've some time.
Thank you very much again.